# Hibernate c3p0 configuration throws TimeoutException

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, jboss, c3p0

I have configured the below hibernate configuration to solve the Database connectivity issue. But while deployment i get the following Exception. I tried to increase the time out parameter, but no solution found.

I am using JBoss AS 7.1 as Application Server and MySQL DB

Hibernate Configuration:

```
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="30"/>
```

**Error**:

```
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from 
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5d43a38e -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
```

can you please give some hint on how to solve this?

Comment: This is not your complete c3p0 configuration. You have a [checkoutTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#checkoutTimeout) set. c3p0 DataSources dump their config to logs at INFO on initialization. You can check that to see your full config. Probably you have a `c3p0.properties` file in your CLASSPATH with extra config, if there are no other `hibernate.c3p0.*` items in your hibernate config.

Comment: I have tried the checkoutTimeout, now i face the following error:

Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
 at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319) [c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:] 


We have the datasource configured in Jboss 7.1 standalone.xml file.
Do any other configuration needed in terms of jboss end?

Comment: 0.9.1.2 is very, very old. please upgrade to 0.9.5.2, the current version of the library. it looks like you have successfully disabled the `checkoutTimeout` in effect previously. your DataSource is unable to acquire Connections from the database. if you check your logs prior to the `CannotAcquireResourceException`, you should see a stack trace of at least one failed attempt to acquire a Connection from the database, which may provide clues about what is going wrong.

Comment: What is the best place to configure C3P0? In applicationcontext.xml  or persistence.xml  . are both same?

Comment: I see no difference. In blogs, they follow these two. Please suggest